# How to define correctly spacy-llm custom task?

Tags: nlp, spacy, openai-api

I'm looking to use spacy-llm to define an unsupervised classification task with GPT-3.5/LLama2. For example:"The Basilica of San Petronio is a minor basilica and church of the Archdiocese of Bologna located in Bologna, Emilia Romagna, northern Italy."

Output: {"Basilica of San Petronio", "minor basilica"}

Do you have any example or good reference you would suggest? Thanks!

I tried following this tutorial with little to no success (https://towardsdatascience.com/elegant-prompt-versioning-and-llm-model-configuration-with-spacy-llm-126b836daad1)